# Analyzing a circuit using simple voltage division instead of Thevinin's theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis

I can use Thevinin's theorem to simplify R1 and R2, and then use the voltage division rule to get the output. However, I want to do it without using Thevinin's theorem. How to analyze the circuit intuitively, perhaps using some extension of the voltage division rule itself?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faQ3Fh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So you want rules or intuition?

Comment: What is implied in the question is that Thevinin's theorem isn't intuitive enough for me yet, so I need a solution using simpler rules.

Comment: I think it should work the other direction. First you learn the formal techniques and then developing your own intuition. Giving you a formula for specific circuit is by no means an intuitive solution.

Comment: Well, here I am trying to develop that intuition with the voltage divider rule.

Comment: Voltage divider rule is not very suitable for this circuit. I would go with node-voltage analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is *intuitive* varies from person to person, but you can use the formula for resistors in series and parallel. The voltage at the unlabeled node between R1 and R2 can be calculated by a voltage division using the combination of R2||(R3+R4), where || denotes resistors in parallel. When you know the voltage at the intermediate node, you can use voltage division again using R3 and R4.

Answer (score 2):

Many of these exercise circuits are drawn in a way intended to confuse the viewer.  I would first re-draw the circuit like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa7DLA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Actually, *I* wouldn't bother re-drawing it, as I can see the pattern in the original drawing, but re-drawing the circuit may help beginners to see what the actual circuit is...)

Now you can see that R3 and R4 form a voltage divider that is in parallel with R2.  Those three resistors together form another voltage divider with R1

I will leave the calculations as an exercise for the student.

Comment: I made the trivial mistake of treating R1 and R2 as a simple voltage divider, ignoring the fact that we first have to simplify R2, R3 and R4 into one resistor, and only then use the voltage divider rule. Pretty simple mistake, but lesson learnt!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to use something you probably don't know about, the [extra element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem).

What complicates this circuit is R2. If you didn't have that in, then the result would simply be V1*(R4)/(R1+R3+R4)... by a simple voltage divider. Another way of stating the same thing is that the transfer function with R2 replaced by an open circuit is $$ H_\infty = R_4/(R_1+R_3+R_4) = 2/5 $$

So far so good, but now we need to apply a correction to account for R2. This is done by calculating a couple of things (all of which are actually very easy here, but I write them out in detail):

- the "ordinary driving-point impedance", Zd, which is from the viewpoint of R2's port (without R2 in the circuit) and with the input (V1) shorted \$Z_d = R1 || (R3+R4) = 12k\Omega. \$
- the "null driving-point impedance" which is again from the viewpoint of R2's port (still without R2) but with V1 in circuit and such that the output is zero. It's trivial to see here that \$Z_n = 0\$, i.e. we need to short R2's port to make the output zero *regardless* of V1's value.

So combining these using the EET formula, the transfer function with \$Z=R_2\$ in circuit is:

$$ H = H_\infty \frac{1+Z_n/Z}{1+ Z_d/Z} = \frac{2}{5}\frac{1+0}{1+\frac{12}{20}} = \frac{2}{5} \frac{5}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$$

So the output voltage is 2.5V/4 = 0.625V.

Comment: Having said this, pipe's method requires slightly less work in this case: one computation of an equivalent resistor, then two voltage dividers, the latter of which requires less computation than the EET formula.

Comment: The null driving-point impedance is measured from R2's port to ground?

Comment: @M.Hassaan: Zn is what you need to replace R2 with so that the output voltage (across R4) becomes zero, even when V1 is not zero. Since there's no way for current [from V1] to flow around the endpoints of R2's port and still get to the output (i.e. flow through R4), if we replace R2 with a short circuit (i.e. zero resistance/impedance element), then the current through R4 becomes zero, and so does the output voltage. Therefore Zn=0. Note that Zn depends on both which element/port is being considered (R2 in this case) *and* across what port the output voltage is measured (R4 in this case.)